# Custom style jQuery Mobile + Phonegap

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to create an app for mobile, using Phonegap 3.4 and jquery 1.11.1 and jquery mobile 1.4.2.

My app has only one page (index.html), containing multiple jquery pages.
I populate this pages by getting some data from a server (using JSON) and populating my pages.
For the page container, everything seems fine, even if transition is a bit slow.

The problem is, I created a fixed navigation bar (using data-role="navbar") with a list (ul) of 4 items.
When a button is active it's blue, and white if not.
My problem is, when I click on another link of the menu, the background become blue (as excepted, because it becomes active), then the css seems to go away for like 0.5s (the link text become purple like a clicked link in a browser, and the background come back to white), then it come back to the active style.

This is breaking the all effect of the transition.

I'm wondering if it's because of the data I dynamically load, but as everything is in the same page, it should be only loaded once. After I just show or hide them.
I have a splash screen while I retrieve data, so when I go to the main part of the app, data should already be loaded.

Here is my html file:

```
   <div id="splashScreen" data-role="none">
      <h1 id="title">Title</h1><br/>
    </div>

    <!-- Main Application -->
    <div id="mainApp">
      <div id="pages">

        <!-- Recent Page -->  
        <div id="recentPage" class="current" data-role="page">

            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="header">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#recentPage" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Recent</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#difficultyPage">Difficulty</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#favoritePage">Favorite</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#donatePage">Donate</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="pageContent" data-role="content">
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Difficulty Page -->
        <div id="difficultyPage" data-role="page">

            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="header">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#recentPage">Recent</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#difficultyPage" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Difficulty</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#favoritePage">Favorite</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#donatePage">Donate</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="pageContent" data-role="content">
                <div id="diff1"><a class="difficultyTab">Difficulty 1 / 10</a></div>
                <div id="diff2"><a class="difficultyTab">Difficulty 2 / 10</a></div>
                <div id="diff3"><a class="difficultyTab">Difficulty 3 / 10</a></div>
                <div id="diff4"><a class="difficultyTab">Difficulty 4 / 10</a></div>
                <div id="diff5"><a class="difficultyTab">Difficulty 5 / 10</a></div>
                <div id="diff6"><a class="difficultyTab">Difficulty 6 / 10</a></div>
                <div id="diff7"><a class="difficultyTab">Difficulty 7 / 10</a></div>
                <div id="diff8"><a class="difficultyTab">Difficulty 8 / 10</a></div>
                <div id="diff9"><a class="difficultyTab">Difficulty 9 / 10</a></div>
                <div id="diff10"><a class="difficultyTab">Difficulty 10 / 10</a></div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Favorite Page -->
        <div id="favoritePage" data-role="page">

            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="header">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#recentPage">Recent</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#difficultyPage">Difficulty</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#favoritePage" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Favorite</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#donatePage">Donate</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="pageContent" data-role="content">
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Donate Page -->
        <div id="donatePage" data-role="page">

            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="header">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#recentPage">Recent</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#difficultyPage">Difficulty</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#favoritePage">Favorite</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#donatePage" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Donate</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="pageContent" data-role="content">
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

at the beginning of the file, I populate the containers of the pages:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
$.mobile.support.cors = true;
//$.mobile.defaultPageTransition='none';
//$.mobile.defaultDialogTransition='none';
$.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay=0;
//$.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled="true";
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/magicline.js"></script>

<!-- PhoneGap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
var dataJSON;
var db = null;

function onDeviceReady() 
{       
    db = window.openDatabase("GalagoFavs", "1.0", "GalagoFavs", 200000);
    db.transaction(createDB,successDB,errorDB);
    getJSONData();
}

function createDB(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GalagoFavs (id unique)");
}

function successDB()
{

}

function errorDB()
{

}

function queryDB(tx,index)
{
    tx.executeSql("SELECT id FROM GalagoFavs WHERE id='"+index+"'",
                    populateFavorite(index));
}

function getJSONData()
{
    // Ajax request
    //
    $url = "http://www.mydomaine.com/JSON/json_get_data.php";
    $.getJSON($url, function(data) 
                       {
                       console.log("Successfully got data from server");
                       dataJSON = data;
                       populatePages();
                       displayPages();
                       });
}

function populatePages() {
    for (var i = 0; i < dataJSON.length; i++)
    {
        populateRecent(i);
        populateDifficulty(i);
        db.transaction(function(tx){queryDB(tx,i);});
    }
}

function populateRecent(index)
{
    if (index < dataJSON.length)
    {
    console.log("Populate recent");
    $("#recentPage .pageContent").append(
                        "<div class='item'>\
                            <div class='TitleName'>\
                                <a class='Title'>"
                                +dataJSON[index].Title+"</a><br/>\
                                <a class='Name'>"
                                +dataJSON[index].Name+"</a>\
                            </div>\
                            <div class='Difficulty'>DIFFICULTY<br/>"
                                +dataJSON[index].Difficulty+" / 10\
                            </div>\
                        </div>");
    }
}

function populateDifficulty(index)
{
    if (index < dataJSON.length)
    {
        console.log("Populate Difficulty");
        $("#difficultyPage .pageContent #diff"+dataJSON[index].Difficulty).append(
                        "<div class='item'>\
                            <div class='TitleName'>\
                                <a class='Title'>"
                                +dataJSON[index].Title+"</a><br/>\
                                <a class='Name'>"
                                +dataJSON[index].Name+"</a>\
                            </div>\
                            <div class='Difficulty'>"
                                +dataJSON[index].Difficulty+" / 10\
                            </div>\
                        </div>");
    }
}

function populateFavorite(index)
{
    console.log("Populate Favorite");
}

// Display main page after loading data
//
function displayPages() 
{
    console.log("Show mainApp");
    //$("#recentPage .pageContent .itemCours:lt(5)").css("display","table");
    $("body #splashScreen").fadeOut(10, function() {
    $("body #mainApp").fadeIn(10);
    });

}

</script>
```

I tried to cache data, to use -webkit-transform:translateZ(0), and lot of other tricks but nothing worked.

I'm not sure if it's a flickering (because it's pretty slow), or if this is an issue like loading page multiple times, or something like that slow down the transitions and everything.

Any help or advice is very welcome.

Thank you.

**Edit**: [Here is a link of the video of what's happening.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5anm8x9aa61mgxx/bug.mp4)

Comment: do you have some images ?

Comment: It's hard because it's an animation, but I can try to get some.

Comment: Here is a link to a video. You can see on the video when I click on a menu on the top, first it's slow, and also when it's transiting menu is acting weird (border change color, background come back to white, text become purple like a visited link,etc...): [LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5anm8x9aa61mgxx/bug.mp4)

Comment: When using debugger I noticed this when calling on a link in the menu. onPageFinished called twice :
05-22 01:02:52.792: D/CordovaWebViewClient(13921): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html#difficultyPage)
05-22 01:02:52.792: D/CordovaActivity(13921): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html#difficultyPage)
05-22 01:02:52.792: D/CordovaWebViewClient(13921): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html#difficultyPage)
05-22 01:02:52.802: D/CordovaActivity(13921): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html#difficultyPage)

Comment: I just checked without loading any data from the javascript (so basically I just have the nav bar), and the problem is still there, so it's not an issue with the amount of data.

Comment: It seems this problem only appears when I use jquery mobile v1.4.0 or above. I tried wit 1.3.2 and the default theme is different (black instead of white button), and then the transition issue seems gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I don't know if this is a bug or not, but since jQuery Mobile 1.4.0, you have to add data-theme="a" (or "b" depending on the theme you want) to the header div.
Otherwise, you get this weird transition style.

I feel like if you don't put anything, it should be "a" by default and you should have the kind of issue I had, but it's not the case for now, so you have to explicitly set the theme.

I hope this could help people having the same issue.

Edit: Here is the code I used in all pages in all pages (for the navbar):

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="header" data-theme="a" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-wrap">
        <ul class="group">
            <li><a href="#recentPage">Recent</a></li>
            <li><a href="#difficultyPage">Difficulty</a></li>
            <li><a href="#favoritePage">Favorite</a></li>
            <li><a href="#donatePage">Donate</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```